# How to block page access to other logged in user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, middleware, django-middleware

I am trying to block logged in user to access other user update profile page.

My situation:

Suppose Person A is logged in to his profile and he know other user update profile URl. In this situation he can simple getting access of the update profile url of other user.
So , here i want to limit this restriction only to the same logged in user to update their profile only.

this is my code for updating profiles:

```
@login_required
def UpdateProfile(request, slug):
    user = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile_pic = form.cleaned_data['profile_pic']
            form.profile_pic = profile_pic
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Data Updated successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('updateaddress', args=(request.user.profile.slug,)))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please check all fields are valid")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    else:
        form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=user)
    context = {
        'user':user,
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, "authentication/register/update/profile.html",context)
```

urls.py

```
path("<slug:slug>/update-profile/", UpdateProfile, name="updateprofile"),
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do like this:

```
@login_required
def UpdateProfile(request, slug):
    user = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    
    if user.id == request.user.id:
        # do something if the id of user you get from the slug matches the actual user id

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            # yada yada yada
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the user object like below

```
@login_required
def UpdateProfile(request, slug):
    user = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if user != request.user:
        message.info("You can't update the other user profile")
        return
```

As described here in django documents :-
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects

You can try something like this in as a decorator

```
def verify_user_profile(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **Kwargs):
        user = Profile.objects.get(slug=args[0])
        if user != request.user:
            return
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **Kwargs)
    return wrapper_func
```

View call will be :-

```
@verify_user_profile
@login_required
def UpdateProfile(request, slug):
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: This code is fine working. Thanks for that. But instead of writing this in each function i wanted to do it by using decorators.

Comment: That's fine you can create a decorator for it.

Comment: help me with this how can I create this decorator

Comment: @PankajKushwaha: you can check the answer have updated the response.

Comment: i am getting this error "tuple index out of range"

Comment: never mind. I made this working. Thank you...